# Continuous Positive Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, continuity, complex-integration

Find all continuous positive functions $f$, if any, defined on $[0,1]$ so that:

$\int_0^1$$f(x)dx=1,$ $\int_0^1$$f(x)$$\sin$$\pi$$x$dx $=$$a$$,$  $\int_0^1$$f(x)$$\sin^2$$\pi$$x$dx $=$$a^2$

where $a$ is a given whole number.

**Attempt**

If we use integration by part and take $u$ as $\sin^2$$\pi$$x$ and $dv$ as $f(x)dx$, then we will get $a=0$ if we solve the third integral.

The problem has been with the second integral. Choosing $u$ as $\sin$$\pi$$x$ leads nowhere and choosing $u$ as $f(x)$ does not help matters as well.

I will really appreciate it if you guys can suggest a way out for me.

Thanks.

Comment: If $a=0$ then no positive $f(x)$ can make the second integral hold .  But, then, no positive $f(x)$ could make the third integral hold either.

Comment: @lulu Could you please be more explicit? How should I go about confirming your claim?

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  Since $f(x)$ is positive, and both $\sin(x)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ are also positive (in the given range), the integrals of the products would have to be strictly positive.

Comment: Oh now I see. Thanks.